# Как поместить целиком внутри Grid-контейнера содержимое (маркированный/немаркированный список) при адаптированной верстке?

Tags: css3, html5, css-grid

Разработал посредством CSS Grid адаптивный (медиазапросы) макет сайта. 
Перешел к наполнению контейнеров (ряд однотипных контейнеров m). В нашем случае для одного из них был создан класс `.art-BlockContent-body`.

Не могу сформулировать правильное медиаправило. Уже и justicy и width делал. Ничего не помогает, как при лэндскейпе (горизонтальной), так при вертикальной ориентации.

Что я упускаю? Каких атрибутов явно не хватает? Подскажите пожалуйста

```css
.art-BlockContent-body {
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 11px;
}

.art-BlockContent {
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.art-BlockContent-body ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #B5B5B5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 6em;
  background-color: #49423d;
}

.head_img {
  background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 66.67%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.footer {
  background-color: Gold;
  height: 50px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #49423d;
}

.main {
  background-color: DimGrey;
}

.m {
  background-color: Gray;
  height: 16.4%;
}

.header,
.main,
.aside,
.m,
.footer {
  border: solid 1px #49423d;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 2fr;
}


/* Smartphones (вертикальная и горизонтальная) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 641px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .header {
    height: 7em;
    padding: 0em 0%;
  }
  .head_img {
    background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 0;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .aside {
    display: none;
  }
  .art-BlockContent-body {
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="head_img">
      <h1> munister-v.github.io
        <h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="aside">Left</div>
    <div class="main">Main</div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="m">
      </div>
      <div class="m">
        <div class="art-BlockContent-body">
          <ul>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=4" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике WordPress">WordPress</a> (3)
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=1" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике Новости">Новости</a> (3)
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=3" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике Плагины">Плагины</a> (1)
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m">Свежие комментарии</div>
      <div class="m">Архивы</div>
      <div class="m">Рубрики</div>
      <div class="m">Мета</div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

https://munister-v.github.io/

[image: Вид с мобильного устройства]

Comment: Список больше чем его родительский блок, уберите свойство высоты у `.m`

Comment: В таком случае, если убрать, то в десктопной (равно как и моб.версии) блоки m не занимают все пространство

Comment: Не подскажите литературу, чтоб максимально грамотно оформлять все в CSS Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете заполнить блок без добавления фиксированой высоты его дочерним элементам. Например с помощью `flexbox`. Или с помощью медиа запросов убирать высоту.

```css
/* ================== */

.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block .m {
  flex: 1;
}


/* ================== */

.art-BlockContent-body {
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 11px;
}

.art-BlockContent {
  justify-self: center;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 1px;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.art-BlockContent-body ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #B5B5B5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 6em;
  background-color: #49423d;
}

.head_img {
  background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 66.67%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  top: 0;
  height: 135px;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.footer {
  background-color: Gold;
  height: 50px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: #49423d;
}

.main {
  background-color: DimGrey;
}

.m {
  background-color: Gray;
}

.header,
.main,
.aside,
.m,
.footer {
  border: solid 1px #49423d;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr 2fr 2fr;
}


/* Smartphones (вертикальная и горизонтальная) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 641px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .header {
    height: 7em;
    padding: 0em 0%;
  }
  .head_img {
    background: url(https://munister-v.github.io/img/Header.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 0;
    height: 120px;
  }
  .aside {
    display: none;
  }
  .art-BlockContent-body {
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="head_img">
      <h1> munister-v.github.io
        <h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="aside">Left</div>
    <div class="main">Main</div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="m">
      </div>
      <div class="m">
        <div class="art-BlockContent-body">
          <ul>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=4" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике WordPress">WordPress</a> (3)
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=1" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике Новости">Новости</a> (3)
            </li>
            <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://www.wpfree.ru/preview/?cat=3" title="Просмотреть все записи в рубрике Плагины">Плагины</a> (1)
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m">Свежие комментарии</div>
      <div class="m">Архивы</div>
      <div class="m">Рубрики</div>
      <div class="m">Мета</div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

P.S. Читайте документацию, [здесь](https://css-live.ru/) так же есть хорошие статьи по гридам.